# Program not returning scanned character

Tags: c, char, scanf

So in my class, part of the homework assignment is to have a function that will return a character that's been entered.

I tried to create this sample code, but it's not working as I hoped.

```
#include <stdio.h>     

char readCharacter();

int main(){
    char x;

    x = readCharacter();

    printf("You inputted %c", x);

    return 0;
}

char readCharacter(){
    char z;
    printf("Input character\n");

    scanf("% c", &z);

    return z;
}
```

I enter a character, I decided to type w, and the program told me the character was some weird funky font.

The actual code from my homework, or rather a snippet from it, is

```
#include <stdio.h>     // needed by printf, scanf()
#include <ctype.h>     // needed by tolower()
#include <stdlib.h>    // for exit()


double readNumber(char *prompt) {
    double val;

    printf("%s", prompt);

    scanf("% lf", &val);

    //if input is not a number, exit program
    if (scanf("%lf", &val) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return val;
}


char readYesOrNo(char* prompt) {
    char yn;

    printf("%s\n", prompt);

    scanf("% c", &yn);

    return yn;
}



int main() {

    double bonus;
    char yesNo;



    yesNo = readYesOrNo("Did the worker get a bonus ? (y/n) ");

    if (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y') {
        bonus = readNumber("Enter bonus: ");
    }
    else {
        bonus = 0;
    }


return 0;
}
```

In the actual homework code, the readYesOrNo function doesn't even wait for me to input anything, it just displays the prompt asking for a y/n response, then goes on to the next line of code, not waiting for user input and assuming a no response.

I have no clue why this isn't working.

Comment: Don't put a space between % and c.

Comment: You're injecting random spaces everywhere. Why?

Answer (score 2):

`% c` is not a valid format specifier.  But `%c` is probably what you meant.

This line:

```
scanf("% c", &z);
```

Needs to be this:

```
scanf("%c", &z);
```

Comment: This fixed the issue in my sample code and in the snippet I posted, but when I tried to apply this change to my actual homework code, the code didn't let me input anything, instead just posting the prompt without letting me type anything in.

My original post has been edited to include my homework code.

Comment: Appologies, instead of the programming just skipping past the input, it actually just crashes.

Comment: I assume you fixed the `scanf("% lf", &val);` line as well, right?

Comment: Also, your `readNumber` function is calling `scanf` twice.  So I have to input the number twice to get that function to return.